# Searching folders with patterns listed in a CSV file and copy them to another location

Tags: bash, find

I have thousands of folders with files inside them and I want to copy some of them in another directory. I have a `.csv` file with two columns with part of the folder name (the folder contain one string value or another, not both).

- Example of folder names:

  ```
  PLASMA_32150129_B5/
  PLASMA_AAA3891784_B3/
  ...
  ```
- The CSV file has no header and the fields are separated by `,`:

  ```
  32150129,AAA0616938
  32140203,AAA3891784
  32140204,AAA0617237
  32140205,AAA0617261
  32140206,AAA0617285
  ...
  ```
- I found this little script as a starting point:

  ```bash
  while IFS=, read -r file rest
  do
    find /path/to/Main_directory -type d -name "${file}" -exec cp '{}' /path/to/New_directory/ \;
  done < mylist.csv
  ```

Now I need to specify that

- the csv values are just a pattern (like `*_32150129 _*`), and
- I want to try pattern in the first column first, and if that doesn't generate a match, try with the other one.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that _both_ columns exist? For example, given the CSV line `32150129,AAA0616938`, can you have a directory called `PLASMA_32150129_B5` and another called `PLASMA_AAA0616938_B5`? Or can we be _sure_ that there will always only be one hit?

Comment: Also, what are the file names you want to copy? Where are those? `mylist.csv`? What format does that have?

Comment: Hello terdon, just one of them exist and the format is like I wrote above. I want all subfolders and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that only one of the columns can actually match, an "or"-type approach might be possible. To do so, perform just a minor modification to your script:

```bash
while IFS=, read -r pattern1 pattern2
do
   find /path/to/start -type d \( -name "*_${pattern1}_*" -o -name "*_${pattern2}_*" \) -exec cp -r '{}' /path/to/target \;
done < filelist.csv
```

- The `-o` operator will ensure that either of the two name patterns generate a match. As long as not both can match (see prerequisite), this will be equivalent to "the second, if the first is not present"
- The parentheses (escaped to prevent interpretation by the shell) are to ensure correct operator precedence.
- Placing the shell arguments to `-name` in double-quotes will ensure the `*` remains *literally there* without being glob-expanded (necessary so that `find` performs the pattern matching during the search, not the shell before passing it to `find`), while still allowing the shell variables `${pattern1}` and `${pattern2}` to be expanded.
- The `-r` option to `cp` is necessary if you want to copy directories and their contents.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, crudest approach which should work if you only ever have *one* match for each pattern in your file, is to just let the shell do the work:

```
tr , '\n' < mylist.csv  | 
    while read pat; do cp -r source_dir/*"$pat"* target_dir/ 2>/dev/null; done
```

That will first convert all `,` in `file.csv` to newline characters:

```
$ tr , '\n' < file.csv
32150129
AAA0616938
32140203
AAA3891784
32140204
AAA0617237
32140205
AAA0617261
32140206
AAA0617285
```

We then read each pattern into the variable `$pat` and just blindly copy `source_dir/*$pat*` (i.e. anything in `source_dir/` matching `$pat`) to the target dir. If nothing matches then nothing is copied, and we get an error message which we discard by using `2>/dev/null`.

---

for a more sophisticated approach, you could do something like this:

```bash
## make sure we don't match the glob pattern itself when no matching
## directories are found
shopt -s nullglob

mainTargetDir=/path/to/Main_directory
sourceDir=/path/to/start
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2; do 
    sourceFiles=("$sourceDir"/*"$f1"* "$sourceDir"/*"$f2"*)
    [ -z "${sourceFiles[@]}" ] || 
        cp -r -- "${sourceFiles[@]}" $mainTargetDir 
done < file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much terdon, your script works perfectly too.